# Regular expression to get following pattern

Tags: c#, regex

Hi I have following line of code

```
{
.....(here i can have anything, numbers, string special characters
...."hello"
}
```

I need to know Regex pattern which finds the above pattern for me, where string starts from { and then some text, then  a keyword like "hello" and then }.

Please help

So i had

```
function test(a,b,c){
}

function test2(c,a,d){
if(a > 0){
    alert('test');
}
```

and i got this expression `function\s+(\S+)\s*\((.|\n)*?\)\s*{`

which gives me `function test(a,b,c)` and

```
function test2(c,a,d)
```

I want a regular expression which gives me function when it finds a keyword like 'test' inside that function.

Makes sense?

Comment: Can you be more specific and post one or two more examples that should be parsed?

Comment: okay let me post something

Comment: does t make any sense now?

Comment: Makes more sense, but this is not something that should be done with regex, although it might be possible with C#'s level of support.

Comment: and how would I do that in C#? Can you provide me some examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know c# but the regex like (with `.` matching linefeed):

```
.*\bfunction\b.+?\bhello\b.+?\}
```

should do the job.

**Explanation:**

```
The regular expression:
(?s-imx:.*\bfunction\b.+?\bhello\b.+?\})
matches as follows:

NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
(?s-imx:                 group, but do not capture (with . matching
                         \n) (case-sensitive) (with ^ and $ matching
                         normally) (matching whitespace and #
                         normally):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*                       any character (0 or more times (matching
                           the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  function                 'function'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  .+?                      any character (1 or more times (matching
                           the least amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  hello                    'hello'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  .+?                      any character (1 or more times (matching
                           the least amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \}                       '}'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
)                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: `function a() {"nothing here"}; function b() { "hello" }` will make your regex fail.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(YourText, @"\{[^}]*""hello"".\}", RegexOptions.Multiline);
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    foreach (Capture capture in match.Captures)
    {
    Console.WriteLine(capture.Value);
}
```

Comment: I think you mean `Singleline`, not `Multiline`, depending on why you included it in the first place.